# Could not calculate build plan: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I'vea build error in Eclipse with m2eclipse plugin (version 0.12.0.20101115-1102):

Could not calculate build plan: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3

I double checked and maven-resources-plugin is available in my local repository, as well as in Maven Repo.

Does anybody know what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be gone with new Version (0.12.1) of m2eclipse plugin

Comment: Error for me was also rectified when used older version of the plugin

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the maven-resources-plugin defined in your project pom.xml?

```
<plugin>
  <groupid>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupid>
  <artifactid>maven-resources-plugin</artifactid>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
</plugin>
```

Even try deleting the folder from your local repository and let it download the jar again.

Comment: I already tried this generic solutions, but without any success.

Comment: Deleting particular trouble-making plugin's folder from .m2 and Maven->Update project helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the folder from the local repository AND THEN restart eclipse.  Just deleting the folder changed the error to a 401 denied for me and then a restart removed that next error completely.

Dean

Answer (score 1):

New to Maven, I also experienced this problem. The generic solution, as posted on [Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources) requires an add-on though, for developers who are still experiencing this problem, as it did not solve the problem for me. I've been struggling for more than an hour already and did the following to resolve the issue:

1. Ensure that Maven has been installed correctly. You can double check by running `mvn --version` via command prompt.
2. Close Eclipse
3. Delete all files in the repository folder (Users\$User$\.m2\repository)
4. Open Eclipse
5. Project > Clean > Clean All Projects > OK
   *Allow the clean to complete
6. Right click on project > Maven > Update Project
7. In the pop-up, ensure that "Update project configuration from pom.xml" and "Clean Projects" is ticked.
8. Click on Ok and allow Maven to reconfigure and download your project's plugins etc.

*Note: I'm running Windows 8.1, using JDK 1.7, Maven 3.2.5 and Eclipse Juno.*

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem. Today I first setup maven and played around with it. Checked that I could use it with command prompt. Then I tried from eclipse. Downloaded m2e, and created a new maven project. Was told by eclipse "Could not calculate build plan: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:... bla bla bla".

Solution: go to .m2 and delete the repository folder. Refresh eclipse (or restart it). Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to solve this issue, I tried many things and finally managed to resolve this issue. please follow the below steps.

1. In eclipse go to 'windows' --> 'preferences'
2. select 'Maven' and then select 'UserSettings'
3. You'll see two files, one 'Global-settings' another 'User-settings'
4. If you are using an external Maven installation, then set the path
   for the 'settings.xml' file of your external Maven package.
5. If you are using eclipse embedded Maven, then it is set by default.
6. in both the cases you need to edit the proxy setting in the 'settings.xml' file, add your Host and port number in the file.
7. Now apply the settings and you can see the issue now resolved. If
   not, restart the eclipse, clean and update the Maven project.