# Eclipse Juno build error with "Maven Project Builder"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, eclipse-juno

When I try to clean & build my Maven project I get the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject
```

similarly with the clean all process, it throws the following:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution"
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project '(Hid Project Name)'.
org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution
```

Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: Are you able to run mvn compile from the command line?

Comment: here you can find your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources

Answer (score 13):

If you are using external maven check if that is selected 
[image]

Also try deleting .m2 and check settings file over there if it is pointing to correct place in localRepository tag

C:\Users\sunny.m2\repository

Comment: Up vote for being the only person to reply to this in 3 years!  I think that deserved a badge.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the Maven installation point, check for 'User Settings' of the Maven too. Mine was pointing to a default location but i had settings.xml somewhere that causes the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I fix mine by correcting the JDK for eclipse (eclipse.ini) vm value.