# Error while creating maven projects in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

When I am trying to create maven projects by eclipse Indigo I am getting error
`" Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5"`

Please help me with solutions.

Comment: Are you creating a new project or importing an existing one?

Comment: @ gowtham :As i m new to this maven creation in eclipse so i followed this link "http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39279/create-a-new-maven-project-in-eclipse/" but  i m not!

Comment: I m creating new project

Comment: @ gowtham: i have started from the scratch so i want to know the necessary plugin for maven.

Comment: You already have m2eclipse plugin in your indigo, so no other thing required for maven projects, try putting maven in online mode.

Comment: @gowtham: i gone through these steps but while creating new projects i m getting the same error as i mentioned above

Comment: @gowtham: from starting itself i m getting error in pom.xml file , i also updated the user settings and reindexed the local repository but not successed

Comment: @gowtham: dr please tell me in what circumstances we get error in pom.xml file and how to recover it.

Comment: ok Project created successfully, showing error in pom file ..right..? check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources