# How to fix Maven, Maven Configuration and Maven Dependency Problems in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**Edit:** I have not resolved this problem yet but this post could be really useful in this kind of problems:

[How to fix your Maven problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12533885/3224038)

---

I did **svn checkout** of my maven project to directory MainDirectory. Everything went well.

Next, I went to MainDirectory and I run command

> mvn clean package

with *BUILD SUCCESS*

I went to directory of my project MainDirectory/MyProject and I run the same command, once again it worked well.

I run Eclipse and I wanted to import "**Existing Maven Projects**". I chose MainDirectory as RootDirectory and I got a warning:

[image: Warning]

I clicked next and I saw few errors:

[image: Errors]

Anyhow, I clicked finish (because of *Action: Resolve Later*)

I was waiting few seconds and I saw this error:

[image: Error2]

but my projects are visible in Project Explorer.

I was carrying on. I imported second "**Existing Maven Projects**" - MainDirectory/MyProject. This time, I had no warning. I clicked next and errors appeared:

[image: Error3]

I clicked finish and another error appeared:

[image: Error4]

Anyhow, new project exists now in Project Explorer.

I went to **Project->Clean** and I chose all my projects. Once again I got an error:

[image: Error5]

Finally, I tried **Maven->Update Project** and another error appeared:

[image: Error6]

I was trying to clean somehow my local repo but I am not sure if I did it correctly.

Finally in Eclipse I see errors as below:

[image]

In fact, I have already done this procedure once few days ago and everything worked perfectly.

When I run my application:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

It works perfectly.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Exactly how did you mavenize Eclipse? Did you install m2eclipse?

Comment: @Gimby No, I did not. In fact, I was following the same procedure few days before and everything was perfect, without any eclipse plugin.

Comment: Well my advice is still to install m2eclipse; I use that and at least I can get my work done without piles and piles of errors ;) But that is no answer, so I'll stay in the commentary shadows. Consider it as a work around if even creating a fresh workspace doesn't help you.

Comment: I think you should put it as an answer. If not for me, maybe for someone in the future it will be helpful.

Comment: A bit more context would be needed so solve this problem. What eclipse version do you use? Have you set the mvn path (.m2)? Have use configured an external maven installation? Have you tryed mvn eclipse:eclipse plugin?

Comment: Please post your `pom.xml` as well as your `$MAVEN_HOME/settings.xml`. To me it seems like a problem in resolving the dependencies. Please also post the version of Eclipses maven version and the one on the command line - which don't have to be (and often aren't) the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have already got this problem, please make sure that the configuration file path of maven is correctly set in your eclipse ?
If you install maven by yourself it is setting with a default path which might not be the same as yours.

Check the following screen to check if you have the good settings, to go here just go to **window->preference** and type maven in the type filter :

[image: Maven Setting]

Answer (score 1):

There may be following solutions-

1. Convert project into maven project(if maven nature is not there in project configuration)
2. Check Maven Dependency Library in Build Path. None of the dependency should throw error.

If problem still persist then-

1. Open terminal, goto the project folder where pom.xml is present and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command in terminal and refresh the project in eclipse.
2. run `mvn clean install` to install jar in local repo(.m2)
   (run `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` if you want to skip test cases.)

It should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Another Stackoverflow user was having a similar problem and there are several things to try listed as answers to that question.  Do any of the workarounds outlined on that question help you?

[Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I changed the apache maven plugin version in **pom.xml** to the version used by the web-app in **web.xml**. Then Maven > Update Project.

Note: The jdk/jre should be compatible to plugins you are using.