# create maven project failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I create a simple maven project in eclipse(indigo), it reports an error:

`Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3`

I found maven-resources-plugin:2.5 in local repo.
I don't understand why my project needs 2.4.3 but not 2.5?

mvn -v:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 16:44:56+0800)
Maven home: D:\Program Files\maven-3.0
Java version: 1.6.0_31, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Check your pom.xml for 2.4.3 version

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources)

Comment: @user987339, I already red this post, I dont understand why new maven project not use 2.5?

Comment: @udalmik, how to check ? I dont add any plugin or dependency in pom.xml.  `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>entry</groupId>
  <artifactId>task</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>`

Comment: ok, so default one should be used. strange, it should be fine for 3.0.4 http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Bindings_for_war_packaging

Comment: Check if eclipse is not able to connect to Internet.

Comment: You need to change default Maven from eclipse to your Maven. You can change it from preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same challenge but it got resolved soon as I created the folder under src/main/resources and saved.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,

just create src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/test/java, src/test/resources

The `maven-resources-plugin` will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Comment: thank you for contributing. please let us know how the code fixes the problem