# Maven project import error messages in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am installing a new Eclipse and tried to import a maven project, but received this annoying message:

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1

Tried both Juno and Kepler, and both reported same problems.

Any idea of what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12533885/1144203

Comment: Could you update your question with the `pom.xml` of the project you are trying to import?