# No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: maven-plugin

I am new to maven and these posts have been of quite a help to me.  I am working in a big company where firewall is on and when I check my proxy setting, it shows Direct. Now I am facing this similar issue (of not able to establish) and have tried almost all the baove options mentioned in this post. Could any one help me please in finding the solution

What I am doing,
After installing and setting up maven,
I did mvn -version to get below result

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:59:2
3+05:30)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

then (following the guidelines to setup JBOSS fuse using maven) I did following command

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.servicemix.tooling
-DarchetypeArtifactId=servicemix-cxf-code-first-osgi-bundle
-DarchetypeVersion=2013.01.0.redhat-610379
-DgroupId=org.fusesource.example
-DartifactId=cxf-basic
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

....and got the following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 o
r one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor fo
r org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plu
gin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-b
eta-5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact d
escriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3
.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact des
criptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metada
ta.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xm
l from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.host.net
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/
to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.host.net
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from h
ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resoluti
on will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or u
pdates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.
plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
): proxy.host.net
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will
 not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates
are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-
metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.host.
net
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.989 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-05T17:40:08+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the
 plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
repositories [local (C:\Users\ayush_tiwari\.m2\repository), central (https://rep
o.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
orPrefixException
```

Please help me with the solution. Please let me know if I need to mention any groupids in my settings.xml or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources)