# Cannot update maven project

Tags: maven

I am unable to update my maven project. I have seen a few others have posted this error to but I still could not resolve this error.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-
plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read 
artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.4
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4 or one of its  
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for   
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.4
```

Comment: detailed expla : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources

Comment: Network proxy etc. problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enter "open" then the below in the terminal:

```
(Unix/Mac) OS X – ~/.m2
(Windows) C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2
```

Then delete everything in the folder. Go back to your project right click it - maven-> update project.

This worked for me...