# How to solve error related maven plugin loading failure

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, jersey

I'm following this tutorial and trying to create simple REST API example

http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/

Every time I convert project to Maven project...This particular error comes up and I'm not able to solve it anyhow ...

```
 Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-          resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

How to solve it .. I already installed maven and set up the Environment variable.

"I have pretty steep timeline" .. any help will be appreciated.
Using Eclipse Mars
Jersey 1.9 bundle of jars

**EDIT**
EXACT ERROR

Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project        'CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample1'.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

Comment: Why not create a Maven project from the start using Eclipse and then add the code from the tutorial?

Comment: I don't have time or idea ...I need to make this one only work...

Comment: Can you help with this one ...  ??

Comment: Try adding the JARs in the stack trace to the Eclipse classpath.

Comment: I tried adding all the mentioned jars, but still giving me the same error.

Comment: Problem is I don't even understand the error.

Comment: http://www.java4s.com/web-services/jersey-hello-world-example-using-jax-rs-specification/
See I found this also .. but it also isn't solving probem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting all the files under the .m2 repository folder and build the project again. [12533885](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885)