# Failed to create maven project in Eclipse Java EE IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

By default, the maven plugin is integrated with the latest Eclipse IDE versions (eg., Mars). However, on creating a Maven project it simply throws the following error:

**Note:** it doesn't undergo any proxy setup

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in
>   http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in
>   http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced

[image]
[image]

**Tool used:**

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources

Comment: yea I understand but its not a proxy issue. just now noticed the problem and added mirrors in the xml file; I think I have given the explicit answer for this question; hope it will help a lot of users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following xml file did trick for me., to do so..

1| Create an xml file (`settings.xml`) in the following location, 
`C:\Users\username\.m2\settings.xml`

2| Copy and paste the below xml snippet that contains multiple mirror tags in it.

3| Save the xml file.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>ibiblio.org</id>
            <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- United States, North Carolina -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>lsu.edu</id>
            <url>http://ibiblio.lsu.edu/main/pub/packages/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- United States, Louisiana -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>sateh.com</id>
            <url>http://maven.sateh.com/repository</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- The Netherlands, Amsterdam -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>dotsrc.org</id>
            <url>http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- Denmark -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>sunsite.dk</id>
            <url>http://mirrors.sunsite.dk/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- Denmark -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>skynet.be</id>
            <url>http://maven2.mirrors.skynet.be/pub/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- Belgium -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>cica.es</id>
            <url>http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- Spain, Sevilla -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>redv.com</id>
            <url>http://mirrors.redv.com/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- Shanghai, China -->
        </mirror>

        <!-- these just point to ibiblio.org -->
        <mirror>
            <id>ibiblio.net</id>
            <url>http://www.ibiblio.net/pub/packages/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- United States, North Carolina -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>ggi-project.org</id>
            <url>http://ftp.ggi-project.org/pub/packages/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <!-- The Netherlands, Amsterdam -->
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>alwaysActiveProfile</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

4| Go to, **Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings**

5| Check User Settings location

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it was disturbing me too but someone gave me this solution and it worked

make sure you are online

- Right-click your project
  -Click on Maven

-Update project

-Force update snapshots/ Releases

-Ok