# Maven dependencies .jar files are not found after deleting .m2 repositry folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i was getting below error while creating Maven Project in Eclipse mars in javaEE perspective.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2
```

So by some search i found that by deleting .m2 repository folder i will get rid of that error.After that i created a maven project in eclipse and gave run as choose maven build->clean install.after this inside libraries in maven dependencies i find only junit-3.8.1.jar file,other .jar files are not found.What should i do to add those .jar files and inside repositry some folders like asm,xmlpull,net,javax,io,commons-lang,commons-io files are missing

any suggestions and answer are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection, so Maven can download the necessary dependencies from Maven central? Or have you configured a custom Maven repository in your settings.xml? If so, is the repository reachable?

Comment: @dunni yes i have working internet connection

Comment: Maybe this link would help - someone had a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources