# couldn't create maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I installed `Maven` a few month ago. I tried create maven project and it was successful. After that I don't use Maven. Yesterday I was trying to download `maven` project from bitbucket but had a problem. I tried to resolve it and even I was trying to create simple maven project. I found a surprise that it wasn't successful. I has such problem, even if I create simple project:[image]
Maybe you have some ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because I searched many pages and nowhere found a solution!

Comment: There's [a related SO thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12533885/146325).   Like the question indicated as a duplicate it proposes a forced update/re-install of the referenced plug-in.  If you want you convince people you have a unique problem you need to list everything you have tried.