# Error while creating simple maven project in eclipse(Mars)

Tags: maven

I am new to the maven, like to create spring integration using maven in eclipse(mars). But getting below while creating the maven project in my local machine. Kindly help me on this.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'samplearticact'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't about Spring Integration: http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/. Please, reformat your question properly in favor the Maven. I've edited your tag to Maven, but you should reconsider them appropriately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources)