# maven - j2objc - No goals have been specified for this build

Tags: java, macos, maven, j2objc, hackintosh

I am trying to build j2objc but get the next error when I issue a `make dist` command:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'dependency' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/lera/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPl..
make[1]: *** [/j2objc-0.9.8.2.1/java_deps/build_result/.maven_generate] Error 1
make: *** [java_deps_dist] Error 2
```

Then i tried a `mvn -X` command:

```
No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

I also followed these suggestions: [Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources) but **it didn't help** because:

1. the maven repositiory server is up;
2. am not behind Proxy;
3. its not about Eclipse;
4. i deleted all contents in my local maven repository - nothing changed;
5. automatically downloaded and installed the dependency plugin - didn't help.

I even tried to add the appropriate line into pluginGroups in maven settings.xml, it didn't help too.
The developer of j2objc mentioned the project only uses Maven so **its dependent jars are copied locally**.

I was also suggested to try a `mvn -X generate-resources dependency:sources` command but i get the next messages:

```
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.5
    org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.5
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:265)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

and many other causes listed.

The pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.j2objc</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2objc</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
  <name>j2objc</name>
  <url>https://github.com/google/j2objc/</url>

  <build>
    <directory>build_result</directory>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Copy dependent jars -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
              <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
              <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>18.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.contenttype</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.200.v20140207-1251</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.registry</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.jobs</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1.v20141014-1248</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.resources</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.1.v20140825-1431</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.expressions</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.filesystem</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0.v20140318-2214</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.app</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.registry</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility</groupId>
          <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.common</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.200.v20130402-1505</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.preferences</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.200.v20140224-1527</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.v20140509-1235</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0.v20140604-1726</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.2.v20150203-1939</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.text</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.text</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.101</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.jarjar</groupId>
      <artifactId>jarjar</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.doclava</groupId>
        <artifactId>doclava</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.jsilver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsilver</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

It should be mentioned that **I am new to maven and am using Hackintosh** so any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the pom.xml file, please?

Comment: @RicardNàcherRoig yes, of course. I edited the question

Comment: I am sorry bit I don't know what are you trying to do. I executed 
mvn -X generate-resources dependency:sources* and it worked. It seems that your internet connection failed for some reason or that your local repository is corrupted. Can you remove/rename your local repository? it is under your home  .m2\repository and try *mvn generate-resources*

Comment: @RicardNàcherRoig I have already done it, too. I am connected to the Internet. Didn't help. The thing which confused me is the message i get in Safari when i try to link almost any website that I didn't link before, for instance: "The certificate for this website is invalid. You might be connecting to a website that is pretending to be “example.website.com”, which could put your confidential information at risk. Would you like to connect to the website anyway?".

Comment: Maybe it's because of a system sertificate that denies access to websites (in my opinion) and it's not expired (there is no expired sertificates in my system), so i cannot delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was about my Hackintosh operating system. If you want to try installing j2objc in Hackintosh, you will probably have same obstacles. I would suggest you to do it in actual OS X. Thank you very much for help!