# Exception occured while Spring starting.please help me

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, apache, spring-mvc

IDE:Idea
FrameWork:Spring+SringMVC+Mybatis+MongoDB+ActiveMQ
Please give me a hand,thanks.

I add others error infomation.
It's strange that while I use "mvn tomcat7:run" to start the project ,it started success! but using debug/run in idea , it occurs these errors.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$FieldCallback;)V
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:418)
```

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 24 15:09:35 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy`

`[2016-08-24 15:09:36] --- [WARN] --- [AbstractApplicationContext.java:887] --- [Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close] --- 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:581)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5786)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1836)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

This is My pom.xml
Please have a look,  thank u.

```
 <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mybatis.version>3.4.1</mybatis.version>
    <mybatis-spring.version>1.3.0</mybatis-spring.version>


    <aspectjweaver.version>1.8.9</aspectjweaver.version>
    <persistence-api.version>1.0.2</persistence-api.version>


    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <mysql-connector.version>5.1.21</mysql-connector.version>
    <druid.version>1.0.4</druid.version>


    <spring-mongodb.version>1.9.1.RELEASE</spring-mongodb.version>
    <spring-boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <mongodb.version>3.2.0</mongodb.version>

    <activemq.version>5.13.2</activemq.version>
    <spring-jms.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-jms.version>
```

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible versions in your pom.xml somewhere: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(...)`

Comment: yes,you are right,but could u tell me what wrong with my versin config?please.

Comment: That's not your complete POM. Run a `mvn dependency:tree` and post the output.

Comment: @dunni Sorry,there is something wrong with my maven...

`[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:3.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Comment: And it's very strange that I use mvn tomcat:run,the project started success.
That make me crazy....

Answer (score 0):

It is a conflict with different versions of the same library.
Run:

```
mvn dependency:tree > dep.txt
```

and check which libraries are duplicated. 
Then exclude conflicting libraries (preferably older version) in pom.xml, by:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-art</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>conf-test</groupId>
                    <artifactId>conf-test-err</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

when "conf-test-err" is the older version to exclude. In your case it will be probably "org.springframework.orm".

Comment: I use mvn:dependency:tree , but show this.....

`[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:3.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Comment: And it's very strange that I use mvn tomcat:run,the project started success.
That make me crazy....

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources