# Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6

Tags: eclipse, maven

while i am tring to create an extrimely simple Eclipse Maven project i had the following error:
*Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6*
may it be a problem related to the proxy? It is necessary to locally install maven ? The setting.xml file have to be manually added? if yes, can someone post an example?
Many thanks in advance,
Pasquale

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you only added a very short part of the error output you have some problems connecting to maven central or to your company repository manager:

based on the following message:

```
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
```