# Spring STS Maven build issue when creating a Maven project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

Hey guys so I'm running into an issue in Spring STS. I've never used this IDE although I know it's based on Eclipse. The version I'm working on is 3.8.4.

I downloaded the IDE in order to work through this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDtZvYAT5Sc&index=8&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x

The problem is that upon creating the project I get the following error:

[image]

I've cleared my repo out completely and tried updating the project and am still getting the same result. I'm not sure if it's relevant but I also have an installation of Eclipse (Luna 4.4.0) and I'm using the embedded Maven installation there. I've got no problems with Maven builds there though.

Comment: Can you use the correct tags? spring-tools-suite should be included but eclipse and java should be excluded.

Comment: [maybe duplicated] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources

Comment: It seems like the maven directory for the dependency got corrupted. Try going to the .m2 directory and deleting the folder for the maven jar plugin.

Comment: Aimee, done. Sorry about that. I'm new here.

Juan, I'll give those a shot and see what comes of it. 

Xtreme Biker, I've nuked the entire repo a few times after deleting just that particular entry and no joy.

Comment: Juan, your link led me to another that suggested using an external installation to download to the mvn repo. Once I did that, the jars came down as usual. Thanks for the reply.