# Getting this error "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6" on creating pom file on maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I get this error whenever i open pom file or try to update the maven project.
I have just setup maven for Eclipse (neon 3) and i get this error.

"Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6"

Can anyone help to solve this issue please?
Also in my maven folder ~/user/.m2 folder i do not see the Settings.xml file. Is this something causing the issue?

Comment: [References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources)

Comment: Does your project build from the command line? You must get that working before bringing Eclipse into the equation.