# Eclipse Maven is blocked

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I tried to use Maven on my company's computer. I use the same issue as in [stackoverflow another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources). I suppose it is the proxy issue. Does anyone know which link I need to ask security to put into white list to use Maven in eclipse?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted, did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the proxy server in eclipse by going to preferences and setting the proxy server your company uses.

[image]

If you don't know your proxy server and are using windows run cmd as administrator and execute this command.

> netsh winhttp show proxy

If you are using another OS Google is your friend, but you need to set the proxy server in network connections of preferences dialog located in windows -> preferences of eclipse and search for proxy.

Another option is to set proxy in your home directory /.m2.settings.xml here is an exmaple
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for your answer. I think your answer should work, but due to some security issue, it does not work for my company computer. Then I ask for a super user access. It works.

Comment: Hi Peter, I agree this stuff is a pain. I work for a pretty large company (AT&T) and their solution is having internal maven repositories that we point to so we don't have to get out to the internet. Good luck! comment if you have any other questions.